# SQL/OracleDB SUM with empty values of second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:
articles (articleID, articleName): All articles (example: 5000 pieces)
sales: (salesID,articleID,salesQty,salesDate): All sales for an article

Now I need a list of all articles, including the sum of the sales. If there are no sales, 0 should be displayed.
The whole should be in a certain time frame.

I have tried the following, but I get only 1000 items and no 0 values.

I have tried the following two queries:

```
SELECT
    article.articleName,
    SUM(NVL(sales.salesQty, 0)) AS qty
FROM article article
LEFT JOIN sales ON (article.articleID=sales.articleID)
WHERE sales.salesDate >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY article.articleName, sales.salesQty

SELECT
    article.articleName,
    SUM(sales.salesQty) AS qty
FROM article article
LEFT JOIN sales ON (article.articleID=sales.articleID)
WHERE sales.salesDate >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY article.articleName, sales.salesQty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the filtering condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.articleName, COALESCE(SUM(s.salesQty), 0) AS qty
FROM article a LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON s.articleID = a.articleID AND
        s.salesDate >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY a.articleName;
```

Note other changes:

- Table aliases that are abbreviation for the table names are easier to write and read.
- The filter on date is in the `ON` clause.
- The `GROUP BY` should only be on the `articleName`.
- The `COALESCE()` is needed *after* the `SUM()` not before -- no need to do the check for every row, just for the final result.
- `COALESCE()` is the standard SQL function, so is preferred over `NVL()`.